# How to show a SnackBar in callback onEvent of EventChannel.listen

Tags: dart, flutter

An event is received from native code using `EventChannel`.

Content is String, and I'd like to show it with `SnackBar`.

But `Scaffold.of` returns null. And I found nothing to get `BuildContext` of `Scaffold` created by `Widget Build(...)`.

The code is like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

showMsg.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(
    (event) => setState(() {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
            content: new Text(event.toString()),
        ));
    }),
    onError: (event) => {}
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT / UPDATED ANSWER**

With the new Flutter update you now have to use `ScaffoldMessenger` to show the `SnackBar`.

```dart
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('test'),
        ),
      );
```

I am using below Flutter version and channel

> 1.24.0-10.1.pre • channel dev •

**OLD ANSWER**

You will need a key for the Scaffold using which you can get the state of the Scaffold

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Now in your `build` method, it must return the scaffold.
in the `Scaffold` assign the `key: _scaffoldKey,`

```
return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      ...,
);
```

using this `key` you can access the state of the `Scaffold`.

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
            content: new Text(event.toString()),
));
```

Comment: Hi. Is the answer works for you ? I'm getting the exception as "The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null." Please advise.

Comment: @ManojArunS don't put the _scaffoldKey in a StatelessWidget. Such state go into a State<> class. Convert your widget to be stateful. I've been having the same issue and finally I realized this is why.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(SnackBarExample());

class SnackBarExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SnackBar Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('SnackBar Example'),
        ),
        body: SnackBarPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SnackBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: Text('This is a SnackBar!'),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Action',
              onPressed: () {
                // Some code to action.
              },
            ),
          );

          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
        child: Text('Showing SnackBar'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```